# How to make histogram with different columns in data set?

Tags: r, text, histogram

I have to make a histogram from the given text file hw4aldData containing:

```
170 172 173 174 174 175 176 177 180 180 180 180 180 181 181 182 182 182 182 184 184 185 186 188
0.84 1.31 1.42 1.03 1.07 1.08 1.04 1.80 1.45 1.60 1.61 2.13 2.15 0.84 1.43 0.90 1.81 1.94 2.68 1.49 2.52 3.00 1.87 3.08
```

But each data set shows up as a different column in R like:

```
         v1   v2    v3   v4   v5
   TankTemp  170   172  173  174 
     EffRat 0.84  1.31 1.42 1.03
```

There are many more data points but I just wanted to show what it looks like. I need to make a histogram for tanktemp and effrate.

I know how to separate columns to make a histogram:

```
hist(hw4aldData$v1)
```

I know how to switch into a transpose matrix:

```
t(hw4aldData)
```

but that doesn't work with the names of the rows at the beginning of the columns.

but I'm not sure how to make a histogram using all the data points in this form, from each of the tanktemp and effrat data.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: `hist(t(hw4aldData[-1])[,i])` where `i` is the data set (i.e. row) . Example `i=1` would be TankTemp and `i=2` would be EffRat.

Comment: Or without transpose `hist(unlist(hw4aldData[i,-1]))`

Comment: is there a way to do it just for the specific row name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in asking a question on Stack Overflow is to create a reproducible example. That is a small example that users can input into their computers to test, diagnose, and solve your issue. It not only helps others but it also enables you to properly assess your problem and potentially find a solution while creating the example.

**Example**

We use the built-in iris data set for values. We only need a few rows and the "Species" label as the first column to look like your example:

```
df <- iris[c(1,80,150),c(5,1:4)]
df
#        Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1       setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 80  versicolor          5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0
# 150  virginica          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8
```

That only took one line and is very helpful in visualizing and sharing the problem you are facing.

**Reproduce the error**

You did not show the error you are receiving but we can show it:

```
hist(df[1,])
Error in hist.default(df[1, ]) : 'x' must be numeric

hist(t(df[,1]))
```

We found the problem, the first column has text and the others do not.

**Solution**

Let's create row names to call from and delete the first column:

```
row.names(df) <- df[,1]
df <- df[-1]
df
#            Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# setosa              5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
# versicolor          5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0
# virginica           5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8
```

Now we can create the histogram by name. Let's try the "setosa" row:

```
hist(unlist(df["setosa",]))
```

Perfect. Cheers.